Почему атрибут herf не работает на тег button?
Я попробовал наложить атрибут herf на тег <button>, но кнопка не перенаправляет на нужный сайт:
    <button herf="https://ru.stackoverflow.com"></button>

Если такой способ не подходит, то как быть?

Ну из очевидного - использовать <a>, а не <button>.

@OliverPatterson, Нужна кнопка, чтобы красивее было.

В чем проблема стилизовать <a> как кнопку?

ну и бонусом из неочевидного - потому что правильнее не herf а href. с чем судя по наличию этой ошибки сразу в трёх местах(заголовок, текст и код) - наверняка столкнулся бы позже, добравшись до рекомендованного выше <a>. p.s. чтоб ссылка выглядела как кнопка за минимум телодвижений можно сделать так: <a style='appearance: button'>

У тега button не существует атрибута href, и тем более не существует тега "herf". Необходимо использовать тег a с атрибутом href.
Справочник по HTML - по тегу button
Справочник по HTML - по тегу a


<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com">text<a>



<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com"><a>

или если нужно чтобы выглядело как кнопка


.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Строчно-блочный элемент */
  background: #FF8000;
  /* Оранжевый цвет фона */
  color: #000;
  /* Черный цвет текста */
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  /* Поля вокруг текста */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Убираем подчёркивание */
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* Скругляем уголки */
}
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" class="btn">text<a>




огромное спасибо за ответ!

На самом деле странный вопрос, делать из кнопки ссылку - всё равно, что делать из ссылки - кнопку. Как по мне простая ссылка (тег a) в этом плане куда более проще кастомизировать, чем ту же кнопку.
Если же вам всё же нужно именно "кнопку-ссылку". Можете использовать следующий код:


<button onclick="window.location.href = 'ваша ссылка'">Go to Homepage</button>




Или без JS <form action="https://ru.stackoverflow.com"><button type="submit">text</button></form>. Но лучше так не делать, конечно.
